# how to interpret and format iterest rates and index returned by aave event

Tags: blockchain

when fetching the values for liquidation call i used this event ReserveDataUpdated that gives me the following values :
Data

```
    liquidityRate :155171829563448810794854241
    stableBorrowRate :232884698058958260939885992
    variableBorrowRate :188004893811414855145714575
    liquidityIndex :1056709698794531321228645934
    variableBorrowIndex :1074990825004844450346840603
```

how to interpret these values like how to convert them to percentage because these values are not understood by a layman.